# C# Is opening and reading from a Stream slow?

Tags: c#, stream

I have 22k text (rtf) files which I must append to one final one.

The code looks something like this:

```
    using (TextWriter mainWriter = new StreamWriter(mainFileName))
    {
        foreach (string currentFile in filesToAppend)
        {
            using (TextReader currentFileRader = new StreamReader(currentFile))
            {
                string fileContent = currentFileRader.ReadToEnd();
                mainWriter.Write(fileContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Clearly, this opens 22k times a stream to read from the files.

My questions are :

1) in general, is opening a stream a slow operation? Is reading from a stream a slow operation ?

2) is there any difference if I read the file as byte[] and append it as byte[] than using the file text?

3) any better ideas to merge 22k files ?

Thanks.

Comment: how large is the file on average?  And How is memory usage of the process?

Comment: The final file will be something like 200-300MB. This is not a problem because I'm not keeping this file into the memory. I'm writing the small files directly into the stream. The small files are relatively small - max 100kb

Comment: Please check the memory usage of the process. I think it might use a lot of memory

Comment: Because of reading the content of the small files into the memory ? If that's your point, @Darim Dimitrov 's solution will remove this problem.

Comment: Anyone remember the old fashioned DOS command `COPY file1.txt /A + file2.txt /A ..... finalfile.txt` ?

Comment: Windows will probably choke on a command line with 22,000 file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) in general, is opening a stream a slow operation?

No, not at all. Opening a stream is blazing fast, it's only a matter of reserving a handle from the underlying Operating System.

> 2) is there any difference if I read the file as byte[] and append it
>   as byte[] than using the file text?

Sure, it might be a bit faster, rather than converting the bytes into strings using some encoding, but the improvement would be negligible (especially if you are dealing with really huge files) compared to what I suggest you in the next point.

> 3) any ways to achieve this better ? ( merge 22k files )

Yes, don't load the contents of every single file in memory, just read it in chunks and spit it to the output stream:

```
using (var output = File.OpenWrite(mainFileName))
{
    foreach (string currentFile in filesToAppend)
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(currentFile))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd782932) method from the BCL will take care of the heavy lifting in my example.

Comment: Beware of BOMs or mixed encodings.

Answer (score 1):

What's slow about reading data from a file is the fact that you aren't moving around electrons which can propagate a signal at speeds that are...really fast.  To read information in files you have to actually spin these metal disks around and use magnets to read data off of them.  These disks are spinning at far slower than electrons can propagate signals through wires.  Regardless of what mechanism you use in code to tell these disks to spin around, you're still going to have to wait for them to go a spinin' and that's going to take time.

Whether you treat the data as bytes or text isn't particularly relevant no.

Comment: Nitpick: electrons are actually moving rather slow in wires. In your common copper wire, they'll be moving at around one meter *per hour*. So yeah, the metal discs are spinning a tiny bit faster :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to speed this up is to make sure that the output file is on a different physical disk drive than the input files.

Also, you can get some increase in speed by creating the output file with a large buffer. For example:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, BufferSize))
{
    using (var mainWriter = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        // do your file copies here
    }
}
```

That said, your primary bottleneck will be opening the files. That's *especially* true if those 22,000 files are all in the same directory. NTFS has some problems with large directories. You're better off splitting that one large directory into, say, 22 directories with 1,000 files each. Opening a file from a directory that contains tens of thousands of files is much slower than opening a file in a directory that has only a few hundred files.